# Getting a UITabBar after breaking out of a UINavigationBar

Tags: ios, ios7, uitabbarcontroller, uinavigationbar, uitabbar

I have a UINavigationBar that has an AuthenticateViewController in it.  Then when the user his Sign In in the upper right of my navigation control, I want to show a UITabBar controller. Do I still create this in appDelegate? How do I "break out" of the UINavigation controller?

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
[super viewDidLoad];
// Do any additional setup after loading the view.

// Add methods for layout of this view controller here

//1
AppDelegate* appDelegate = [UIApplication sharedApplication].delegate;
//2
self.managedObjectContext = appDelegate.managedObjectContext;

[self.navigationItem setHidesBackButton:YES];

// Now add the Sign In button
UIBarButtonItem *signinButton = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithTitle:@"Sign In" style:UIBarButtonItemStylePlain target:self action:@selector(signinButtonPressed:)];

self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = signinButton;
}

- (void) signinButtonPressed:(UIBarButtonItem *) sender
{
    // What goes here to start the UITabBars
}
```

Comment: Do you want to navigate to a new page (after signing in) wherein you see tab bars?

Comment: Yes I want the navigation bar gone and a fresh tab bar controller with a few tabs.

Comment: So, you can still create a tab bar controller and then push it along with your navigation controller when the sign in button pressed. You can then hide your navigation bar on top. Got it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set your `TabBarController` as `rootViewController` after signed in.

Your button action would be like this:

```
UITabBarController *tabBarController = [[UITabBarController alloc] init];
tabBarController.viewControllers = @[<your viewControllers>];

AppDelegate *appDelegate = [UIApplication sharedApplication].delegate;
[appDelegate.window setRootViewController:tabBarController];
```

Edit: You might don't get use with array creation with `@[]`. So here is an explanation:

```
UIViewController *viewController1 = [[UIViewController alloc] init];
UIViewController *viewController2 = [[UIViewController alloc] init];

// Two methods of adding item to array

// First method
NSArray *array = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:viewController1, viewController2, nil];

// or 
NSArray *array = @[viewController1, viewController2];

tabBarController.viewControllers = array;
```

Comment: i have it like this, but how do I make the tab bar items themselves?

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to do a `modalTransition` to jump out of the `navigationController`.. this will keep the `AuthenticateViewController` as `RootViewController` of the `window`.. if you want to change the `RootViewController` as well then you'll need to get the AppDelegate's window and change its `RootViewController` to the `TabBarController` you'll make here… hope you got it..